# Reserve the width of vertical bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know if there is a way to reserve the space used by the vertical bar. When there is no bar, the page put some padding or margin on the right, but if the vertical bar is needed, it consumes this area.

Why this? Because my content is shaking from right to the left when a vertical bar appears, and this is annoying me.

I am using bootstrap 3, and this example can be used as test: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/NJsYw/9/)

```
overflow-y
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can set a padding-right on the body.  But, what about people using macs or touch screen devices that don't show that physical scrollbar?

Comment: Some ul li and div elements are not closing correctly you can see them as red in the fiddler

Comment: @davidpauljunior: This is a intranet only website for pcs and no mobile. Thanks.

Comment: @RickyStam: This is just a test base, I think the solution will not be impacted by the unclosed divs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to force the vertical scrollbar to always appear.

See [CSS for forcing the browser to display scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864549/css-for-forcing-the-browser-to-display-scrollbar)

Comment: I am using it actually... but the aesthetics isn't good. Yeah, I am minimalist. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's far from pretty. @Khrys were you able to finally find a better solution?