# Keeping scrollbar visible in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

When you create a scrolling table using the DataTables plug-in for JQuery, the scrollbar is by design invisible until the user brings focus to the table. I want the scrollbar to be continuously visible, because it lets the user knows that they can, in fact, scroll.

Answer (score 2):

This is 3 years late. But hope this helps someone else

```
.dataTables_scrollBody{overflow-y: scroll;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS for that . I believe the syntax is `html {overflow-y: scroll; }`

Also the question was answered here:

[CSS for forcing the browser to display scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864549/css-for-forcing-the-browser-to-display-scrollbar)